# Which command line command do I have to enter to get a scheduled task with certain parameters? (Batch/CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

With the following command I want to create a scheduled task to devmgmt.msc:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN "devmgmt-task" /sc once /st 00:00 /TR C:\Windows\system32\devmgmt.msc /RU %username% /RL HIGHEST
```

---

As a parameter (parameter field) in the Windows task planning (taskschd.msc, GUI) I would like the following code line:

```
/k set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1&start "" devmgmt.msc&exit
```

---

My question: How do I have to modify the above command so that the scheduled task comes into Windows? Where are several "" characters required?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the QUOTATION MARK characters? `^"`